# Android application supported by 0 Devices

Tags: java, android, xml, google-play

I have developed a chatting application that works fine on my testing devices. but when i publish it on play store, the supported devices is 0. Therefore it is not showing in the **play store app** but it is showing in the play store website.

[image]

**Required permissions 9 permissions**

```
android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS
android.permission.INTERNET
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS
android.permission.WAKE_LOCK
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

**Features 4 features**

```
android.hardware.FAKETOUCH
android.hardware.LOCATION
android.hardware.location.GPS
android.hardware.location.NETWORK
```

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=zupportdesk.desk.zupport.chatsystem

**build.gradle**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "zupportdesk.desk.zupport.chatsystem"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.2.16.11.04"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/gson-2.2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/signalr-client-sdk-android.jar')
    compile files('libs/signalr-client-sdk.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'br.com.liveo:navigationdrawer-material:2.5.1'
    compile 'org.java-websocket:Java-WebSocket:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.1.jar')
    compile 'net.gotev:uploadservice:2.1'


    compile ('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'){
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
    }
}
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="zupportdesk.desk.zupport.chatsystem">

    <!-- **************************** Permission ************************************************ -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!-- **************************************************************************************** -->
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!-- ************************** Activity ************************************************ -->
        <activity
            android:name=".Login"
            android:noHistory="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ForgotPassword"
            android:launchMode= "singleInstance"/>
        <activity android:name=".CompanyProfile"
            android:launchMode= "singleInstance"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".Settings"
            android:label="Settings"
            android:launchMode= "singleInstance"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".ChatsTab"
            android:label="Dashboard"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:launchMode= "singleInstance"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".UserDetails"
            android:label="User Details"
            android:launchMode= "singleInstance"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".Chatting"
            android:launchMode= "singleInstance"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".Operators"
            android:label="All Operators"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:launchMode= "singleInstance"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".CannedResponses"
            android:label="Canned Responses"
            android:launchMode= "singleInstance"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".ChatHistory"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:launchMode= "singleInstance"/>
        <!-- ************************************************************************************ -->


        <!-- ************************** Service ************************************************* -->
        <service
            android:name=".Services.SignalRService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:stopWithTask="true" />
        <service
            android:name=".Services.SelectVisitorService"
            android:enabled="true" />
        <!-- ************************************************************************************ -->


        <!-- ************************** Meta Data *********************************************** -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
        <!-- ************************************************************************************ -->


    </application>

</manifest>
```

can someone help me to fix this issue. TNX.

Comment: what did you upload to google play store , universal apk for all architecture or an apk for each architecture(arembe, x86 etc)?

Comment: its a universal apk for all architecture

Comment: using a depreceated library might cause this issues useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy', check in that percpective

Comment: even after removing org.apache library and using  `useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy` i am getting the same error